# clearInterval after 10sec doesnt work

Tags: clearinterval

I created a little Game and that should create every 1sec a enemy till there are 10 enemy (10sec)
if i do it without clearInterval it creates the whole time enemys 
so i want to stop when it reach 10

```
var initEnemy = function ()
{
    //enemy div
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    var timerid = null;
    function IntervalFunction()
    {
        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 190);
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        enemy.push(new Enemy(randomX, randomY).create());
    }
    IntervalFunction();
    setInterval(IntervalFunction,1000);
    clearInterval(IntervalFunction),10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval` doesn't take second argument.

And setTimeout is easier to wrap head around... A simple approach is to count how many enemies you've created so far and not run `setTimeout` when the limit is reached:

```
var initEnemies = function () {

    var numEnemiesCreated = 0;

    function createAnotherEnemy() {
        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 190);
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        enemy.push(new Enemy(randomX, randomY).create());

        numEnemiesCreated += 1;
        if (numEnemiesCreated < 10)
            setTimeout(createAnotherEnemy, 1000);

    }

    createAnotherEnemy();
}
```

And a version with for loop, it schedules function calls 0s, 1s, 2s, ... , 9s from now:

```
var initEnemies = function () {

    function createEnemy() {
        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 190);
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        enemy.push(new Enemy(randomX, randomY).create());
    }


    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++)
        setTimeout(createEnemy, i * 1000);
}
```

**update**

Here's a version with `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. You still have to count how many enemies you've created so far, and you have to use interval id in `clearInterval` call. Haven't tested this, sorry!

```
var initEnemies = function () {
    var numEnemiesCreated = 0;
    var intervalId;

    function createEnemy() {
        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 190);
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        enemy.push(new Enemy(randomX, randomY).create());

        // Unschedule ourselves after 10th run
        numEnemiesCreated += 1;
        if (numEnemiesCreated == 10)
            clearInterval(intervalId);    
    }


    intervalId = setInterval(createEnemy, 1000);
}
```

Comment: is there no way with clearinterval cause my teacher told me to use that

Comment: btw it doesnt work it creates 5 enemys and after these 5 he creates the whole time 10 enemy at once